# How do I open a MHTML file in Python?

Tags: python, mhtml

I am trying to open a .mht file in my local system. But it is throwing me File Not Found Error even if the file exists. THis MHTML file is the output of the step recorder in Windows. I want to extract only the text in the file.

The function I used to open the file is:

```
with open(mi_file) as fp
```

where `mi_file` is holding the file name.

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/swapn/PycharmProjects/StepRecorderAutomation/mhtml_parsing.py", line 40, in <module>
    with open(mi_file) as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Recording_20200528_1557.mht'
```

Could someone please help me to find what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It can't get the file. Check the path again.

Comment: please try to call `open` with full absolute path to your file `mi_file`.

Comment: Still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: The error message is an evidence that you are using an IDE (Pycharm). Nothing bad, but the working directory may not be what you would expect. You should either print it to make sure and copy the file there, or use a full path for the file.

Comment: Ok, I got it and now it is working fine. Thanks to all who replied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be solved by two options:

**Option 1:** Go to the file location and set that as working directory.

**Option 2:** Copy the full path of the file location and save it in mi_file.
mi_file = ('path of the file')